# I/O classes buffering

Tags: java, io, buffering

I know that since Java 1.5 `PrintWriter` preforms internal buffering even if it created with `PrintWriter(String fileName)` constructor. So i don't need tedious decoration like this:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("File")));
```

So I am wondering whether it still make sense to manually decorate *Streams/Readers/Writers* classes or `PrintWriter` is a particular case? For instance:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("File")));
```

In all tutorials such things declared without `BufferedOutputStream`. But does it really improve performance or not? Or now i can just use constructors without intermediate buffer's constructor with current I/O classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `PrintWriter` would be a particular case. It's constructor internally does

```
public PrintWriter(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName))),
         false);
}
```

but same does not happen for `ObjectOutputStream` and definitely cannot be generalized that decorators are not needed and can the same functionality is added in new constructor implementation. For instance -

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("File")));
```

You are saying I want to write to a file, buffer the contents (to reduce multiple write calls) and finally you decorate the resultant `OutputStream` so that you can serialize/deserialize it.

Also in my opinion there should not be any performance impact with using decorators versus using the corresponding constructor because at the end of the day you are doing the same thing.

> Then why in all Serialization tutorials(for example) ObjectOutputStream is created without buffering?

As for serialization `ObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out)` wraps the OutputStream  out with `BlockDataOutputStream` which itself is a buffered output stream so you don't need a separate `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. _'buffer the contents (to reduce multiple read calls)'_ — so that thing doesn't really improve performance? Then when buffering is useful?

Comment: It definitely increases performance. I was comparing the the use of decorators versus similar implementation provided in constructor.

Comment: Then why in all Serialization tutorials(for example) `ObjectOutputStream` is created without buffering? This thing is confusing me.

Comment: For output streams buffering implied reducing write called (I mentioned read call earlier, my bad, that if for buffered reading). Updated answer for Serialization part.